# InvalidArgumentException : Invalid CRON field value 30 at position 4

Tags: laravel, cron

I tried To run this command **php artisan schedule:run** on laravel project I got this error

InvalidArgumentException  : Invalid CRON field value 30 at position 4

```
 at /var/www/vendor/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/CronExpression.php:155
    151|      */
    152|     public function setPart($position, $value)
    153|     {
    154|         if (!$this->fieldFactory->getField($position)->validate($value)) {
  > 155|             throw new InvalidArgumentException(
    156|                 'Invalid CRON field value ' . $value . ' at position ' . $position
    157|             );
    158|         }
    159|
```

this is command on my Kernel

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // Schedule to delete old messages every old days
        $schedule -> command(DeleteOldMessages::class, ['days' => config('marketplace.days_old_messages')])
                    ->days(config('marketplace.days_old_messages'));

        // Make the command for releasing purchases runs each X days
        $schedule -> command(ReleasePurchasesCommand::class, ['days' => config('marketplace.days_old_purchases')])
                    ->days(config('marketplace.days_old_purchases'));

        // Run completing command for purchases every defined number of days
        $schedule -> command(CompletePurchaseCommand::class) -> days(config('marketplace.days_complete'));

    }
```

I dont know what issue is

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: open tinker and type `config('marketplace')` then paste the result here

Comment: [
     "rsa_key_length" => 4096,
     "mnemonic_length" => 24,
     "product_types" => [],
     "vendor_fee" => 10,
     "vendor_dwc_tag_count" => 1,
     "vendor_low_value_feedback" => 70,
     "products_per_page" => 24,
     "days_complete" => 2,
     "days_old_messages" => 30,
     "days_old_purchases" => 20,
   ]

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler `->days()` function is expecting an array of days of the week on which the task should run. For instance ([1,3,5]) meaning run on Monday,Wednesday and Friday)

I assume with values of 20 and 30, you are expecting the tasks to run at a specified *interval*. This is not possible with cron based scheduling.

What you probably want is to run the tasks every day and within the task, determine if any records exceed the specified limits.